# Best practices of changing domain name?

Tags: domains

My current personal website is `myusername.github.io`, and I own another domain name provided by my school, `myschool.edu/~myusername`. So I want change my website's domain name to my school one.

Considering in the future I may move to another school/company, I don't think it is a good practice to just copy everything over from GitHub to my school host. Instead, a better practice, I think, is to change the domain name and keep the web content still on GitHub.

So I tried to do so and found [a tutorial by GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-www-subdomain/). It seems that I
need some instructions from the school on how to set up the `CNAME` file? The school refused to do so, but I doubt I really can't do this myself?

Suggestions of other good practices are very welcome!

Comment: `myschool.edu/~myusername` is a _username_, not a domain name. You're not going to be able to edit the DNS tables for your school to add a `CNAME`, you'll need to purchase an actual domain name which would then provide that ability. You might however be able to _redirect_ users to your GitHub site using JavaScript, a meta refresh, or a server-side language if they permit it (unlikely).

Comment: @dan thanks a lot dan. sorry for my confusion -- quite a new, unprofessional webmaster. but i can put an `index.html` in side my home folder on our school server. then people can visit my `index.html`. as such `myschool.edu/~myusername` is still not considered as a domain name?

Comment: A domain name is the `myschool.edu` part of the URL, otherwise referred to as an _apex domain_ in this GitHub help doc on [Using a custom domain with GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/).